# No warnings for redundant adoption in Protocols and Classes

Tags: swift

In the following example, the **Object** class type conforms to both the **Square** and **Rect** protocol.

```
protocol Rect {
    var angle: Int { get }
}

protocol Square: Rect {
    var isSquare: Bool { get }
}

class Object: Square, Rect {
    var angle: Int = 90
    var isSquare: Bool = true
}
```

Since the **Square** protocol already inherited the **Rect** Protocol, the **Rect** adoption should be redundant in the **Object**'s declaration. However, Xcode doesn't show any warnings, when I changed **Rect** and **Square** to class type, there is no warning either. Does anyone know the reason? Thanks

Comment: A protocol doesn’t conform to another protocol, it inherits it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift compiler does not complain about redundant protocol adoption in the actual type declaration — only in an extension declaration, and only if the same declaration (not an implicitly inherited declaration) has already been made.

For example:

```
class Object: Square {
    var angle: Int = 90
    var isSquare: Bool = true
}

extension Object: Rect {} // legal

extension Object: Square {} // not legal, because you already said that
```

This is actually a good thing for humans, because in complex situations it is nice to be able to write

```
class Object: Square, Rect
```

...because this reminds you, the human, that the adoption of Square implies the adoption of Rect. In a project with a lot of mutually dependent protocols that can be really, really helpful, as I can tell you from experience.